# Safe startup and accessibility services

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, services, blackberry

I have a Blackberry DTEK 50 (android 6.0)

When I set the option to have a pin set at startup ( security option special to blackberry? ) then accessibility services will not run (as far as I understand it)

Has anybody else have this problem and is there a way around it ( outside disabling safe startup)

Comment: Accessibility Service should still run. Are you unable to run them. In which case please add a screenshot showing errors

Comment: I think it is a bit chicken and eggs , when I activate an accessibility service the startup pin disappears,  when I set a startup pin accessibility services are stopped not sure what  screens it's you would need and how to get them

Comment: I checked on 6.0 on Moto X Play 1. I can activate accessibility services despite apps having that permission and activating PIN ( I normally use swipe ) 2. There is a standard dialogue that says PIN can't be used for encryption because accessibility Service is activated. Maybe what you are seeing is a Blackberry implementation, which I am not familiar with